# How open a child dialogue out of a parent dialogue but out of its boundaries?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I am building an asp.net project in which i need to open some pop-up dialogues to interact with the user. however, i am now stuck in a place where i need to open a dialuge out from another dialogue. the task is easy and very normal. but the problem is the new dialogue is opened within the boundries of the first dialogue, which very annoying for users, and moreover, makes the  application ugly.

please give me a hand and give me the approach i can make any dialgue appears outter of his parent's boundaries..

[image]

I tried to make a div into the most parent window by using RegisterStartupScript while i am in the first dialogue , but i discovered RegisterStartupScript only works with the active window (may be because it needs reload to take effect, but it is not valid since user is interacting with the dialogue).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, popping a bunch of moveable dialogs is like 20 years ago, and you don't want to "think" of windows applications when it comes to web land. Worse yet, all the rage is SPA's (single page applications).

And worse yet?

With the rise of smartphones, tablets etc., then popping up movable windows tends to be a REALLY bad idea on touch devices (users hate having to "try" and move windows around). The so-called multiple document interface is LONG gone in our industry.

And Worse yet?

Just try to make that UI "responsive" with different sized screens, and you in for EVEN more hurt and pain for your users.

However, I suppose in some cases you could nest 2 deep, but beyond 2 dialogs deep will be a painful experience for the end user.

Next up:

If you going down this road, then you want/need/should/great idea to adopt some kind of dialog system since you often can't use JavaScript window.open() due to popup blockers.

So, there are boatloads of dialog systems, and bootstrap dialogs, and jQuery.UI dialogs are perhaps the most common. As soon as you start nesting dialogs, then jQuery.UI will be far better and more flexible than bootstrap dialogs.

So, say this example:

[image]

So, in above, we have a GridView, and then we click on a row edit button for editing that one record (our first dialog). And inside of that dialog, we have a delete button, and thus that is our 2nd nested dialog to confirm the delete.

And note how in above, the 2nd dialog is "limited" to staying inside the first dialog.

So, our markup for this is rather simple:

We assume thus we have jQuery, and jQuery.UI (jQuery.UI has the .dialog widget we are using here).

So, the GridView markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%"
            DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Descripiton" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    ItemStyle-Width="140px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
                            ImageUrl="~/Content/edit2.png"
                            Width="48px"
                            Height="40px"
                            OnClick="cmdEdit_Click"
                            Style="margin-left: 15px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Our code to load the GridView:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()
    GridView1.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

And now our row button click - pops the first dialog:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    fLoader(EditRecord, rstData.Rows(0))  ' code to load div
    ' pop the dialog client side
    Dim sJava As String = $"myedit('{btn.ClientID}')"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "MyPop", sJava, True)


End Sub
```

Ok, so now our client-side JavaScript:

The jQuery.UI dialog code for first popup looks like this:

```
<script>
    function myedit(Sbtn) {
        var btn = $('#' + Sbtn)
        myDialog = $("#EditRecord")
        myDialog.dialog({
            title: "Edit Hotel",
            modal: true,
            sizable: true,
            width: '830',
            closeText: "",
            dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
            position: { my: 'right top', at: 'left bottom', of: btn }
        })
    }

</script>
```

So, all above does is pop our first "div" that becomes the edit dialog.

Inside of that "edit div", we have the 2nd nested div that becomes our 2nd popup dialog.

So, the delete button in our markup (to launch the 2nd nested popup dialog) is thus this:

```
    <asp:LinkButton id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left:15px"
        OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this)"
        OnClick="cmdDelete_Click1"
        >
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>

    <div id="deldivprompt" style="display: none">
        <h3> Delete Hotel = 
            <asp:Label ID="lblDelPrompt" 
                runat="server" Text=""
                f="HotelName"
                ></asp:Label>
        </h3>
        <h4><i>(This cannot be un-done</i></h4>
    </div>

        <script>

            var mydelok = false
            function mydelprompt(btn) {

                if (mydelok) {
                    mydelok = false
                    return true
                }
                myDialog2 = $("#deldivprompt")
                myDialog2.dialog({
                    autoOpen: "false",
                    title: "Delete this Hotel",
                    modal: true,
                    sizable: true,
                    width: '380',
                    closeText: "",
                    position: { my: 'left bottom', at: 'left top', of: btn },
                    dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            id: "MyDelete",
                            text: "Delete",
                            class: "myshadow",
                            click: function () {
                                myDialog2.dialog('close')
                                mydelok = true
                                btn.click()
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            id: "MyCancel",
                            text: "Cancel",
                            class: "myshadow",
                            click: function () {
                                myDialog2.dialog('close')
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })

                myDialog2.parent().draggable({ containment: '#EditRecord' })
                myDialog2.dialog('open')
                
                return false
            }

        </script>
```

So, we pop the dialog, and then we use jQuery.UI "draggable" to limit the 2nd popup dialog to be contained inside of our EditRecord div (our first popup dialog).

And note how I return "true" for that dialog to the server-side button click (to delete). If that routine returns false, then the server side delete button code does not run. If user clicks on the dialog "delete" button, then the code returns true. And note carefully how that button click event controls the server-side button to run or not. This setup works without having to use a JavaScript promise, yet the dialog code remains as asynchronous.

So, you can nest/popup a dialog, and limit the location (movement) of that dialog to a given div.

However, if the goal is to allow the 2nd dialog to move and NOT be limited to inside of the first dialog?

Then simply remove this line of code:

```
myDialog2.parent().draggable({ containment: '#EditRecord' })
```

Now the result is this:

[image]